# Get distance between multiple points in mongodb Geojson

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson

So I've got the following model:

```
Ride
{
location: {type: "Point", coordinates:[]},
waypoints: {type: "Multipoint", coordinates: [[Number]]} 
//array of coordinates
}
```

I need to be able to get the total distance of ride i.e sum of the distance between any two waypoints. How do I write a query for this. I am assuming multipoint means something in Mongodb

What sort of index do I need on waypoints?
Is this the correct way of storing waypoints?